# The Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

From the wikipedia page, I know that the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{R}$ can be identified with itself, by identifying each $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ with the character $x\mapsto e^{ 2\pi i\xi x}$. But I don't know show that every character is the form of $x\mapsto e^{2\pi i\xi x}$. Given a character $\chi:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$, how to determine the unique real number $\xi$ such that $\chi(x)=e^{2\pi i\xi x}$? It seems that we can only determine $\xi$ up to an integer.

Comment: $e^{2 i \pi \xi x} = e^{2 i \pi (\xi x+ k )}$ but $e^{2 i \pi \xi x} \ne e^{2 i \pi (\xi + k )x}$ when $x$ is not an integer, and recovering $\xi$ can be done by differentiation

Comment: @user1952009 A character is a continuous homomorphism, it may not be differentiable.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't want to use differentiation, it is a circular argument.

Comment: if you know the value of $\chi$ for every $x$ you can recover $\xi$, what is the problem !!! ? it is undeterminated if you know the value of $\chi$  only for a finite (or countably finite) number of $x$ all integer multiple of a same $a$ (or something like that)

Comment: @user1952009 How can you guarantee that such a $\xi$ exists?  I know that if $\xi$ exists then it is unique.

Comment: I mean the answer of your first question is what I wrote. so now you have other questions ? and of course I can guarantee that if $\frac{\chi'(x)}{\chi(x)}$ is constant then $\chi(x) = C e^{2 i \pi \xi x}$ for some $\xi,C$ ... (what should imply the definition of a continuous homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$)

Comment: @user1952009 No. From wikipedia, such a $\xi$ must exist, but I don't know how to determine it.

Comment: I answered to the "it seems that we can only determine ξ up to an integer" part : it is false